# POST Nested Json to API With Jquery Ajax & Get Response With PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, rest

I want to Post a Json string or PHP array to a Restful API and get the response without reloading the page. So, I want to use Ajax and/or jquery. So far, I'm failing miserably. my code is below.

I've tried several jquery methods - some using stringify and others just sending raw json. I'm not getting enough response or error of any kind to know where I need to look to solve the problem.

```
 $(".avm_zip").on("click", function() {
 $.ajax({
    url: "REMOVED",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
    "Header": {
        "UserId": "REMOVED",
        "Password": "REMOVED",
        "SourceApplication": "Dev Service Tester"
    },
    "Property": {
        "StreetAddress": "10345 W Briar Oaks Dr # E",
        "City": "Stanton",
        "State": "CA",
        "Zip": "90680",
        "APN": null,
        "PropertyType": null
    },
    "Order": {
        "CustomerOrderReference": "Test LITE",
        "PreferenceTableName": "VeroLITE TEST",
        "Price": null,
        "Credit": null,
        "AdditionalFields": null
    }
},
    dataType:'json',
    success: function (response) {
       alert("Success");
    },
    error: function(error){
        alert("Something went wrong");
    },
});
```

The API is more robust and centered on XML. Getting the basic call & retrieval set up using Json had challenges because of this. So, it is possible that is bleeding over into this effort.

Comment: I am using the click action to trigger the function with alerts to see if working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. PHP is a Server Side scripting language where JavaScript/jQuery is Client Side. In PHP you will use cURL where as jQuery you can use AJAX. They are vastly different. For the code you have tested, what are the Network Console results that you see?